# How to remove all `/` characters present at the end of a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.9 and Ruby 1.9.3. Given a string I would like to remove *all* `/` characters present *at the end* of that string. That is, for instance:

```
From "abc/"   to "abc"
From "abc//"  to "abc"
From "abc///" to "abc"
...
From "a/b/c///" to "a/b/c"
```

How can I make that (maybe by using a regex)?

---

I tried:

```
string = string[0,string.length-1] if string.end_with?('/')
```

but it works just for one character.

Comment: @Rohit Jain - I tried `string = string[0,string.length-1] if string.end_with?('/')`, but it works just for *one* character.

Comment: Just replace: - `\/+$` with an empty string. See http://rubular.com/r/qLOXmIUgmT

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"abc//".sub %r{/+$}, ''
```

this will only delete `/` at the end of the string.
I use `%r{}` to make a regexp because I don't have to escape the `/` in this case.

Comment: I prefer to use `sub(/\/+$/, '')`.

Comment: Then do that^^ Also note that @Valery Kvon is right: `$` matches line ends `\n`,too. Use `\z` instead if you want to match only the string end.

Comment: @user12882: `"I prefer to use sub(/\/+$/, '')"`. That causes what's called "[leaning toothpick syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome)", and is discouraged because it makes it more difficult to read and maintain.

Comment: I would also suggest that this depends on who is reading and maintaining it.

Answer (score 2):

Some benchmarks are in order.

Because Perry Horwich's answer is basically the same as Huluk's, I figured they'd have the same results. Heh, I was wrong. After looking at it and realizing it was doing a string search instead of a regex, I fixed it and added the fixed test.

After that, I did some fiddling to see what I could come up with. My solutions don't seem to be as straightforward as others, but the first does the job equally fast for short strings, maybe a tiny bit faster on the long strings. The second two are a wash as far as when dealing with short string or long, but both are very fast. I reverted to old-school techniques and did them how we'd do it in assembler "back in the day."

```
require 'benchmark'

n = 1_000_000

def huluk(s)
  s.sub %r{/+$}, ''
end

def apneadiving1(your_string)
  matches = your_string.match(/(.*?)\/*$/)
  matches[1]
end

def apneadiving2(your_string)
  your_string.scan(/(.*?)\/*$/).flatten.first
end

def fixed_perry_horwich(my_beginning_string)
  my_beginning_string.sub(/\/+$/,'')
end

def the_tin_man1(s)
  s.split(%r[/+$]).first
end

def the_tin_man2(s)
  s = s[0..-2] while s[-1] == '/'
  s
end

def the_tin_man3(s)
  s_len = s.length - 1
  s_len -= 1 while s[s_len] == '/'
  s[0..s_len]
end

puts "Ruby #{ RUBY_VERSION }"
puts "#{ n } iterations"

puts

[
  'abc//',
  'abc' * 50 + '//',
  'abc' * 10 + '////',
  '////////////'
].each do |sample_string|

  puts "sample string: #{ sample_string }"
  puts 'huluk:               %s' % huluk(sample_string)
  puts 'perry_horwich:       %s' % perry_horwich(sample_string)
  puts 'fixed_perry_horwich: %s' % fixed_perry_horwich(sample_string)
  puts 'apneadiving1:        %s' % apneadiving1(sample_string)
  puts 'apneadiving2:        %s' % apneadiving2(sample_string)
  puts 'the_tin_man1:        %s' % the_tin_man1(sample_string)
  puts 'the_tin_man2:        %s' % the_tin_man2(sample_string)
  puts 'the_tin_man3:        %s' % the_tin_man3(sample_string)
  puts

  Benchmark.bm(19) do |b|
    2.times do
      b.report('huluk')               { n.times { huluk(sample_string)               } }
      b.report('fixed_perry_horwich') { n.times { fixed_perry_horwich(sample_string) } }
      b.report('apneadiving1')        { n.times { apneadiving1(sample_string)        } }
      b.report('apneadiving2')        { n.times { apneadiving2(sample_string)        } }
      b.report('the_tin_man1')        { n.times { the_tin_man1(sample_string)        } }
      b.report('the_tin_man2')        { n.times { the_tin_man2(sample_string)        } }
      b.report('the_tin_man3')        { n.times { the_tin_man3(sample_string)        } }
      puts
    end
  end

  puts

end
```

---

Results:

```
Ruby 1.9.3
1000000 iterations
```

```
sample string: abc//
huluk:               abc
perry_horwich:       abc//
fixed_perry_horwich: abc
apneadiving1:        abc
apneadiving2:        abc
the_tin_man1:        abc
the_tin_man2:        abc
the_tin_man3:        abc

                          user     system      total        real
huluk                 1.840000   0.000000   1.840000 (  1.849929)
fixed_perry_horwich   1.840000   0.010000   1.850000 (  1.847069)
apneadiving1          1.900000   0.010000   1.910000 (  1.900817)
apneadiving2          4.860000   0.010000   4.870000 (  4.883103)
the_tin_man1          1.830000   0.000000   1.830000 (  1.826547)
the_tin_man2          1.150000   0.000000   1.150000 (  1.151420)
the_tin_man3          1.170000   0.010000   1.180000 (  1.168161)

huluk                 1.820000   0.000000   1.820000 (  1.825440)
fixed_perry_horwich   1.830000   0.000000   1.830000 (  1.827306)
apneadiving1          1.850000   0.000000   1.850000 (  1.853751)
apneadiving2          4.830000   0.000000   4.830000 (  4.825394)
the_tin_man1          1.810000   0.000000   1.810000 (  1.811503)
the_tin_man2          1.150000   0.000000   1.150000 (  1.151865)
the_tin_man3          1.170000   0.000000   1.170000 (  1.172259)
```

```
sample string: abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc//
huluk:               abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc
perry_horwich:       abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc//
fixed_perry_horwich: abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc
apneadiving1:        abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc
apneadiving2:        abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc
the_tin_man1:        abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc
the_tin_man2:        abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc
the_tin_man3:        abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc

                          user     system      total        real
huluk                 2.120000   0.000000   2.120000 (  2.122156)
fixed_perry_horwich   2.130000   0.010000   2.140000 (  2.136665)
apneadiving1          9.630000   0.030000   9.660000 (  9.656817)
apneadiving2         12.420000   0.030000  12.450000 ( 12.459432)
the_tin_man1          2.080000   0.010000   2.090000 (  2.090112)
the_tin_man2          1.570000   0.010000   1.580000 (  1.573887)
the_tin_man3          1.380000   0.000000   1.380000 (  1.388120)

huluk                 2.130000   0.010000   2.140000 (  2.134414)
fixed_perry_horwich   2.120000   0.010000   2.130000 (  2.129399)
apneadiving1          9.620000   0.020000   9.640000 (  9.646624)
apneadiving2         12.410000   0.020000  12.430000 ( 12.423327)
the_tin_man1          2.080000   0.010000   2.090000 (  2.090938)
the_tin_man2          1.580000   0.010000   1.590000 (  1.581131)
the_tin_man3          1.390000   0.000000   1.390000 (  1.400093)
```

```
sample string: abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc////
huluk:               abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc
perry_horwich:       abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc////
fixed_perry_horwich: abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc
apneadiving1:        abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc
apneadiving2:        abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc
the_tin_man1:        abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc
the_tin_man2:        abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc
the_tin_man3:        abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc

                          user     system      total        real
huluk                 1.980000   0.010000   1.990000 (  1.983149)
fixed_perry_horwich   1.970000   0.010000   1.980000 (  1.979796)
apneadiving1          3.500000   0.010000   3.510000 (  3.513885)
apneadiving2          6.320000   0.020000   6.340000 (  6.348327)
the_tin_man1          2.070000   0.010000   2.080000 (  2.075045)
the_tin_man2          2.800000   0.000000   2.800000 (  2.801136)
the_tin_man3          1.840000   0.010000   1.850000 (  1.851506)

huluk                 1.980000   0.010000   1.990000 (  1.980867)
fixed_perry_horwich   1.980000   0.010000   1.990000 (  1.984776)
apneadiving1          3.510000   0.010000   3.520000 (  3.523383)
apneadiving2          6.340000   0.020000   6.360000 (  6.357442)
the_tin_man1          2.070000   0.000000   2.070000 (  2.074559)
the_tin_man2          2.800000   0.010000   2.810000 (  2.814275)
the_tin_man3          1.850000   0.010000   1.860000 (  1.855621)
```

```
sample string: ////////////
huluk:               
perry_horwich:       ////////////
fixed_perry_horwich: 
apneadiving1:        
apneadiving2:        
the_tin_man1:        
the_tin_man2:        
the_tin_man3:        

                          user     system      total        real
huluk                 1.980000   0.010000   1.990000 (  1.982700)
fixed_perry_horwich   1.980000   0.010000   1.990000 (  1.984354)
apneadiving1          1.860000   0.000000   1.860000 (  1.869155)
apneadiving2          4.840000   0.020000   4.860000 (  4.852445)
the_tin_man1          2.010000   0.000000   2.010000 (  2.020292)
the_tin_man2          5.060000   0.020000   5.080000 (  5.070202)
the_tin_man3          6.390000   0.020000   6.410000 (  6.412697)

huluk                 1.980000   0.010000   1.990000 (  1.987652)
fixed_perry_horwich   1.980000   0.010000   1.990000 (  1.981360)
apneadiving1          1.860000   0.000000   1.860000 (  1.871577)
apneadiving2          4.850000   0.020000   4.870000 (  4.857329)
the_tin_man1          2.010000   0.010000   2.020000 (  2.023877)
the_tin_man2          5.060000   0.010000   5.070000 (  5.067753)
the_tin_man3          6.410000   0.020000   6.430000 (  6.434523)
```

I tried to bracket the simple case of `"abc//"` and something I'd consider a "worser-case" of 152 characters, to antagonize the patterns and algorithms presented.

`huluk` and `fixed_perry_horwich` are a wash as far as which is faster, because the difference between them is compiled away as the source is interpreted by Ruby.

---

EDIT:

A couple changes:

- I refactored the code to DRY it up.
- I removed the `perry_horwich` test from the benchmarks, because it made no sense to test it.
- I added a test for `'////////////'` at @pguardiario's recommendation. It shows the result of a worst-case test stripping the delimiters.

The take-away from the test results is to look at the sort of data being tested and select the algorithm that works best for the input. What works well for some inputs doesn't necessarily work as well for others. I found it interesting that the "old-school" methods outran solutions using regex for short trailing-delimiter strings. I think that's a result of Ruby setting up the calls to compiled code. Once the delimiter string got longer, the compiled code would have an advantage.

Comment: Interesting, +1 for the effort

Comment: You stacked the deck a bit with that benchmark though. Try: sample_string = '///////////'

Comment: @pguardiario Hmm. Not intentionally. I'll add it to the benchmarks and post the results... good catch. I added the test and posted new results.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regexp to retrieve the expected part of the string:

```
/(.*?)\/*$/
```

See on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/LDNGMK6YpJ).

```
reg = /(.*?)\/*$/
matches = your_string.match(reg)
result = matches[1] 

#or
result = your_string.scan(reg).flatten.first
```

Comment: Can you provide a code example (not just the regex) on how you'd use that regex?

Comment: This goes at it backwards though. It's more straightforward to remove the offending characters using a `sub`, than it is to capture everything up to the target characters, and then access the capture array. As is, you're doing more work.

Comment: @theTinMan Funny you tell getting the desired output is more backward than removing the undesired characters. Really.

Comment: Take a look at the benchmark results and you'll see my point.

Comment: @theTinMan performance is one thing, you were arguing about straightfulness though

Comment: I'm arguing both. A straight forward algorithm is most often easier to maintain and, again, most often faster. My comment about work was referring to the CPU. That's born out by the benchmarks.

Comment: @theTinMan My opinion is that it's absurd not to be able to get match result more easily. I want a part of the string (straight), not a modified string based on the original string (backward).

Comment: To me this is fine but I would go with the more accurate and less verbose: str[/(.*?)\/*\Z/, 1]

Answer (score 0):

This will work for your example:

```
my_no_slash_terminated_string = my_beginning_string.sub(/\/+$/,'')
```

Consider if you want to account for white space at or near the end of the string as well.

Comment: This doesn't work because it's trying to do a sub-string search (`"\/+$"`) instead of a regular expression (`/\/+$/`).